# Easy way to format a string to hh:mm format

Tags: c#

Please suggest an easy way to format a string entered by the user to 12 hr time with colon as specified below rather than checking with if length = 1,length =2, etc

```
Entered String  Formatted String(hh:mm)
 6               06:00
 12              12:00
 220             02:20
 1212            12:12
```

Comment: There isn't really a "simple" way to do this. You'll either have to perform the conversion yourself based on the length/content of the string or split the input into hours, minutes, and seconds fields.

Comment: What would be the format of 111 or 112?

Comment: @RashikHasnat I imagine that 1-2 digits would be a whole hour value while 3-4 digits is an hour/minute value, so "111" would be `01:11`.

Comment: Did you try *anything*?

Comment: I think you should instead focus on capturing the time in the correct format.  Your current approach is open to all sorts of user input errors.

Comment: There is no easy way to restrict the user to type only the valid time in a Xamarin forms Entry box. The invalid time will be cleared on the out of focus event of the entry using Regex validation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the input will always be between 1 and 4 characters, perhaps you can check whether the input length is odd or even to determine if the parsed value starts with a "0" or not, and the rest is just padding 0's to the right - something like this:

```
string ParseTime(string input)
{
    bool odd = (input.Length % 2 > 0);
    var result = (odd ? "0" : "") + input.PadRight(odd ? 3 : 4, '0');   
    return result.Insert(2, ":");
}
```